# How to estimate the AI player's strength in multiplayer game?

Tags: game-ai, monte-carlo-tree-search

I have implemented multiple MCTS based AI players for the Love Letter game ([rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Letter_(card_game))). It is a 2-4 players zero sum card game where players make alternating moves. I am struggling with how to properly conduct experiments for estimating AI player strength against human players:

1. In 2 player game where one of the players is AI bot
2. In 4 player game where one (or multiple) of players is AI bot

Comment: Do you have data (preferably lots) regarding human play choices? Do you have some humans available to help testing?

Comment: @NeilSlater I don't have human play data. However, I have some humans availlable to help me in testing. Is it good approach to take 15 players (including 1 AI bot)  with initial Elo rating and let them play against each other?

Comment: If you are only concerned with win/loss outcomes, you can use the ELO system.

Answer (score 2):

The following are extremely simple ways of tackling this problem.

### A very simple way

It can simply be
`strength of AI`=`(# of games won)`/`(total # of games)`.

### In case data for each move is available

Something like
`score per game`=`# of correct decisions`/`total number of decisions`.
Then
`strength of AI`=`sum(score per game)`/`total # of games`.

### If each move/decision has a score associated with it

then you do
`score per move`=`scored points by taking a decision`/`maximum possible score`.
then
`score per game`=`sum(score per move)`/`total # of moves`
and finally,
`strength of AI`=`sum(score per game)`/`total # of games`.

### How to choose optimal number of games to play?

It depends on your requirements. If you want to report your AI's strength in percentage of the games it played correct to 1 decimal place (for example, this AI won 95.1%) then 10000 is an optimal number of games your AI needs to play. Suppose your AI won 9508 games out of 10000 then you will have 95.08% strength of AI. To be able to correctly round it to 1 decimal place you need to have an additional decimal place so that you can quote the strength of you AI with reasonable confidence, in this case 95.1%.

Comment: Can you explain how to select optimal number of total games  and how many people to engage for the experiment?

Comment: I have tried to explain the optimal number of total games in the edit of the answer above.

Comment: I am not sure how you can determine the optimal number of people to choose.

Comment: Isn't this the relative strength of AI to a particular player?

Comment: @DuttaA That's true, most probably. It very well looks like it as well.

Comment: This experiment can be repeated against multiple people who are aware of how to play the game. Then average strength can be reported as the final one.

Comment: The experiment can also be repeated with only one top tier human player and an average can be reported